# Terraform and route 53: redirect to home router with nginx load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, ssl

I own a domain name, let's say `fancydomain.com` (managed through AWS). I also have a kubernetes cluster running somewhere (but not on AWS), with a nginx ingress controller that acts as a load balancer. I have the IP of the load balancer.

I would like to point the domain name to the IP of the load balancer, and I would like the load balancer to handle the TLS certificate. But I'm struggling in two places:

- It looks like I'm failing to properly redirect to the IP of the LB
- I don't understand how/where the TLS certificate (created by AWS) should be integrated

So far this is my terraform:

```yaml
resource "aws_route53domains_registered_domain" "fancydomain" {
  domain_name   = var.domain_name
  auto_renew    = true
  
  name_server {
    name = "ns-709.awsdns-24.net"
  }
  name_server {
    name = "ns-1732.awsdns-24.co.uk"
  }
  name_server {
    name = "ns-1144.awsdns-15.org"
  }
  name_server {
    name = "ns-434.awsdns-54.com"
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "fancydomain_zone" {
  name = var.domain_name
}

# Create an ACM Certificate
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "fancydomain_certificate" {
  domain_name       = var.domain_name
  validation_method = "EMAIL"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
  allow_overwrite = true
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.fancydomain_zone.zone_id
  name    = var.domain_name
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = 300

  records = ["this.is.my.serverip"]
}
```

Also, the nginx load balancer *does* work at the moment. It uses a self-signed certificate, and if I lure my computer by modifying the `/etc/hosts` like below, I managed to access the domain by querying `https://fancydomain.com`.:

`/etc/hosts`

```
1.2.3.4 fancydomain.com
```

Any idea what I could try to get unstuck?

EDIT: The name servers for the registered domain are the same as the hosted zone's ones:

[image]

[image]

Comment: you need to connect the nameservers of the route53 zone to the registered domain.  Right now you've told the registrar to refer to `something1.com` and `something2.com` , those have to be the nameservers from the route53 zone to expose the record you create in that zone.

Comment: this is anonymised/simplified, in reality they do match. I also tried removing them and letting AWS choose them for me.

Comment: You're sure the nameservers in the route53 zone are the exact same as the ones you have in your domain?  With what you have you'd have to have run the terraform for route 53 then hard coded the resultant nameservers into the terraform.

Comment: I double checked and edited my question to show they are. I also put the real name servers values in the terraform snippet.

Comment: That certainly looks right.  And I take it you found your A record in that particular zone ( I see 3 records, and 2 - NS and SOA - come automatically) .   You can try lookup with `dig @ns-709.awsdns-24.net fancydomain.com` You can check nameservers with `whois fancydomain.com`

Comment: I think you were right about the name servers not matching. Using a data source to make sure they were in sync solved the problem, see my answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately I think @erik258 was right, I think the name servers of the registered domain probably weren't in sync with the ones from the hosted zone. I ended up using a data source for the name servers of the zone, and I used it to set the ones in the register domain. Behold:

```yaml
resource "aws_route53domains_registered_domain" "fancydomain" {
  depends_on = [aws_route53_zone.fancydomain_zone]

  domain_name   = var.domain_name
  auto_renew    = true
  
  #Choose Enable/True (to lock the domain) or Disable/False (to unlock the domain).
  transfer_lock = true

  dynamic "name_server" {
    for_each = data.aws_route53_zone.fancydomain_zone.name_servers

    content {
      name = name_server.value
    }
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "prod"
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "fancydomain_zone" {
  name = var.domain_name
}

data "aws_route53_zone" "fancydomain_zone" {
  name = var.domain_name
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
  allow_overwrite = true
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.fancydomain_zone.zone_id
  name    = var.domain_name
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = 300

  records = ["my.ip.here"]
}
```

After I applied that it started working. Still not 100% sure of what was the problem before.

Answer (score 1):

The free certificate that ACM provides is meant to be used in AWS managed services only(like ALB, CloudFront etc.). There is no way to download it and use it elsewhere. In your case, you have the load-balancer/nginx outside of AWS, so it can't be used. I do not see any issue with the aws_route53_record above.

Comment: gotcha, thanks. I'll try something else for the certificate.
The record still doesn't work though, it looks like it doesn't redirect to the IP I want.